# serialising the psql resultset with array_agg in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have 2 tables with data

```
tripsheet=# select * from t1;
 c1 | c2 
----+----
  1 |  2
  1 |  3
(2 rows)

tripsheet=# select * from t2;
 c3 | c4 
----+----
  1 | 11
  1 | 12
(2 rows)
```

With query

```
tripsheet=# select t1.*,array_agg(t2.*) from t1, t2 where t1.c1 = t2.c3 group by t1.c1, t1.c2;
 c1 | c2 |      array_agg      
----+----+---------------------
  1 |  3 | {"(1,11)","(1,12)"}
  1 |  2 | {"(1,11)","(1,12)"}
(2 rows)
```

I am using java jdbc to process the result set, I am not able to convert the (1,11) to respective pojo.

following is my code

```
String sql="select t1.*,array_agg(t2.*) from t1, t2 where t1.c1 = t2.c3 group by t1.c1, t1.c2;";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                Array array = rs.getArray("array_agg");
                Object[] ints = (Object[]) array.getArray();
                ResultSet rs2 = array.getResultSet();
                while(rs2.next()) {
                    rs2.getObject(1);
                    System.out.println(rs2.getObject(2));
                }
            }
```

I am able to get result as

```
(1,11)
(1,12)
(1,11)
(1,12)
```

But I could not break them further to get individual fields 1 and 11.

The above tuples/object are of org.postgresql.util.PGobject this should be mapped to T2 pojo.

Is it possible to convert PGobject to T2 pojo?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the array directly in the expected type like this:

```
(Integer[]) rs.getArray("array_agg").getArray()
```

And then you can just transform it to a list:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList((Integer[]) rs.getArray("array_agg").getArray());
```